# Tensorflow can't append batches together after doing the first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, tf.data.dataset

I am running into problems with my code after I removed the loss function of the `compile` step (set it equal to `loss=None`) and added one with the intention of adding another, loss function through the `add_loss` method. I can call `fit` and it trains for one epoch but then I get this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128,) (117,) (128,)
```

My batch size is 128. It looks like `117` is somehow dependent on the number of examples that I am using. When I vary the number of examples, I get different numbers from `117`. They are all my number of examples mod my batch size. I am at a loss about how to fix this issue. I am using `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` as input.

I have the following simplified model:

```
class MyModel(Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()

    encoder_input = layers.Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE, name='encoder_input')
    x = encoder_input
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)

    encoded = layers.Dense(LATENT_DIM, name='encoded')(x)

    self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, outputs=[encoded])

    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Input(shape=LATENT_DIM),
      layers.Dense(32 * 32 * 32),
      layers.Reshape((32, 32, 32)),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
      layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)

    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)

    # Loss function. Has to be here because I intend to add another, more layer-interdependent, loss function.
    r_loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(x - decoded), axis=[1, 2, 3])
    self.add_loss(r_loss)

    return decoded


def read_tfrecord(example):
  example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, CELEB_A_FORMAT)
  image = decode_image(example['image'])

  return image, image

def load_dataset(filenames, func):
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
    filenames
  )

  dataset = dataset.map(partial(func), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

  return dataset

def train_autoencoder():
  filenames_train = glob.glob(TRAIN_PATH)
  train_dataset_x_x = load_dataset(filenames_train[:4], func=read_tfrecord)

  autoencoder = Autoencoder()

  # The loss function used to be defined here and everything worked fine before.
  def r_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=[1, 2, 3])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

  autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=None)

  autoencoder.fit(train_dataset_x_x.batch(AUTOENCODER_BATCH_SIZE),
                  epochs=AUTOENCODER_NUM_EPOCHS,
                  shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the value of `INPUT_SHAPE`?

Comment: @dsillman2000, It's `INPUT_SHAPE = (128, 128, 3)`

Comment: Could be more batch-size-flexible if you change that to `(None, 128, 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get rid of the error and don't care about the last "remainder" batch of your dataset, you can use the keyword argument `drop_remainder=True` inside of `train_dataset_x_x.batch()`, that way all of your batches will be the same size.

FYI, it's usually better practice to batch your dataset outside of the function call for `fit`:

```py
data = data.batch(32)
model.fit(data)
```

Comment: Dropping the remainder is acceptable workaround at the moment. Great quick answer!

Answer (score -1):

the loss function can not be set in the call method .
the call method is intended to make a forward pass not to copute the loss .

u need to add the loss function in the compile method or after it

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's a valid recommendation to the author, but it should be a comment rather than an answer.